# remove non unique numerical character

Tags: string, awk, grep

input

```
pattern01 pattern11
pattern02 NonNumeric pattern12
```

ouput

```
pattern01 pattern11
pattern02 pattern12
```

pattern0x has got a length from 7 to 15 characters which can be numerical or '.'

patthern1x has got length between 2 and 4 numerical characters

NonNumric is a unique strickly non numerical character

ex: 
input

```
12.1 58
135454& 548
124.485* 5587
12.58.336./ 54
```

output

```
12.1 58
135454 548
124.485 5587
12.58.336. 54
```

thank you very much!

Comment: `sed 's/[^0-9. ]//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sed using below:

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9. ]//g' test.txt
```